# DEADLINE_EXCEEDED when try to use AutoML Vision client with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-platform, automl

I'm trying to get started as an AutoML Vision client for the Google Cloud Platform in Java. Simplified the program, it seems to me, to the limit:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import com.google.cloud.automl.v1.AutoMlClient;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1.Dataset;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1.LocationName;

public class Create_DS {

      public static void main(String[] args)
          throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

          try (AutoMlClient autoMlClient = AutoMlClient.create()) {
              LocationName parent = LocationName.of("zimin-77", "us-central1");
              Dataset dataset = Dataset.newBuilder().build();
              Dataset response = autoMlClient.createDatasetAsync(parent.toString(), dataset).get();
              System.out.format("LocationName.of() Location name:%s",response.getDescription());
          }        
      }
}
```

And in any case, when I start, I get a message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.944791400s. [buffered_nanos=4948378600, waiting_for_connection]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:564)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:545)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:86)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
    at com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.get(OperationFutureImpl.java:127)
    at sid_ii.Create_DS.main(Create_DS.java:19)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.944791400s. [buffered_nanos=4948378600, waiting_for_connection]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:51)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1050)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1176)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:969)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:760)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:545)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:515)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$1CloseInContext.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:416)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.944791400s. [buffered_nanos=4948378600, waiting_for_connection]
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 13 more
```

I can not do anything !!! Fantasy is over. (((Please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are having issues when testing the AutoML Vision client on your machine.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors) specifies that a DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error message is thrown because the request did not finish within the deadline. In [other services](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-codes) the same deadline error can be caused by client runtime, network connectivity, or even firewall.

[The AutoML Vision API Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tutorial) tutorial has Java Code to create the dataset (Step 1: Create the Flowers dataset) with the same method you are using:

```
client.createDatasetAsync(projectLocation, dataset)
```

I have followed the guide and it ran correctly in Cloud Shell. In order to discard any issue with the API from your machine or VM instance, try the tutorial code from the Cloud Shell.

Comment: Good morning Aldo!
Thank you for your advice. Used them. I began to understand the classes of the com.google.cloud.automl.v1 package more deeply.
Aldo, maybe you know what parameter of the AutoMlSettings class you can control the deadline value to eliminate the exception io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.952640500s.
How to increase this value?
Thank you again, Aldo.

Comment: Regarding your question about increasing the timeout of the automl class, in case you are sending more than one job to the AutoML Vision API, try using java queues to send one job after another, also, in your code you are not catching the errors, please try catching the jobs that exceeded the timeout and sends you the DeadlineExceededException to retry. I also found another StackOverflow [1] issue related to the same issue and the problem was with the csv file the client was sending to the AutoML API.

[1] https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-automl/issues/289